# How to access classes in src from classes in packages

Tags: java, class, oop, import

I was thinking about Java packaging. It is a little confusing for me. I wonder to which package, base classes belong? For example this is my project structure. How can I use `User` class in `registerMenu` class?

[image]

Comment: post your question and information here, don't just post links for us to visit. Most likely, by using import statements. This is just a thought after reading what you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class in `src` means a class without a package, that means a class in the default package. You can't import a class in the default package.

Therefore you must either implement that class in a package or use reflection to use that class in other classes that are in packages.

Answer (score 1):

Well... in this case, How about declare 'User class' as a variable without import and approach it?!

Like this

registerMenu.java

```
...
public class registerMenu ...{
    User u = new User();
    ...
}
```

When accessing public variables or methods in `User class`, 
You can approach it as

```
u.var; 
u.method();
```

But I am sorry for I don't know if this is the recommended way.